# How to show some certain columns in datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

After querying from database, I fill the result into dataset, suppose there are 10 columns.

And then i have to show 5 of the 10 columns into datagridview.

My way is to create a new DataTable with the 5 columns, and copy the value from the original dataset. It works, but i don't think it's a good way.

Any suggestion? 

----------------------- 
I am using C# for Form Application.
I prefer programic way to implement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hide selected column by setting Visible to false, like `datagridview.Columns[0].Visible = false`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you set the dataset as the datasource of the gridview,  you can specify which columns do you want to display in the gridview by clicking on the > button in the design view and selecting edit columns.

Please see the following article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx

Comment: thanks.My datagridview didn't bind with any dataset in UI. therefore this is no column for selection in UI, i think. Can I specify which columns to show in code?